# injecting spring bean in java 8 function

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, inversion-of-control, java-8

This is a how I do it as well as a **should I do it** question.

I have a case where I need to use instances managed by *Spring* in a `Lambda` function. 
In short I want `DummyBranch`, `MandrillBranch` objects and other branches to be managed by *Spring*.

```java
public class QOSStrategy {

  public static Function<DistributionMessage, List<Feedback>> executeQOS = (message)-> {
    QOSFilters qosFilters = new QOSFilters();
    List<Branch> providers = qosFilters.getProviderByQOs(message, 
    Arrays.asList(new DummyEmailBranch(), 
        new MandrillBranch(), 
        new EverbrideBranch(), 
        new JavaMailBranch(), 
        new DirectSMSBranch()));
  }
}
```

One option I see is to get it from the *Spring* *application-context*. But is there a way to do it using `Annotation`s.

Thanks
-Parshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autowire Collection of all beans which implement the same interface.

See Spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html).

Comment: Just curious. Is there a benefit to passing the Bean collection instead of just passing the Application Context and do appContext.getBean? The reason I ask is that I have a lamda function calling another lambda function.

Comment: It is basically your style choice. We find it fun and easy to unit-test with Mock/InjectMocks annotations by Mockito. See http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21 Code looks cleaner imho, up to you though really.

Answer (score 1):

I created a QOSBean which is managed by spring. Here is what it ended up-

```
public class QOSStrategy {

public static Function<DistributionMessage,CustomBean, List<Feedback>> executeQOS = (message, qosbean)-> {
QOSFilters qosFilters = (QOSBean)qosbean.getQosFilters();
        List<Branch> providers = qosFilters.getProviderByQOs(message, qosbean.getAllProviders());
}
}



public class QOSBean implements CustomBean {

@Autowired
private QOSFilters qosFilters;

@Autowired
private Branch dummyEmailProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch dummySMSProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch dummyVoiceProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch directSMSProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch everbridgeProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch mandrillProvider;
@Autowired
private Branch javaMailProvider;

public QOSFilters getQosFilters() {
    return qosFilters;
}

public Branch getDummyEmailProvider() {
    return dummyEmailProvider;
}

public Branch getDummySMSProvider() {
    return dummySMSProvider;
}

public List<Branch> getAllProviders (){
    return Arrays.asList(dummyEmailProvider, dummySMSProvider, dummyVoiceProvider, directSMSProvider, everbridgeProvider, mandrillProvider, javaMailProvider);
}
```

}